# How do I create a foreign key in rails 5 if I've already created the models for the tables I want to associate?

Tags: foreign-keys, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations, rails-postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5.1

All of the references I've found either show me how to do it upon table creation, or are for a much earlier version of rails. Ideally, I'd like like the foreign_key to be named 'author_id' in the questions table to distinguish it from other users who may be leaving comments or answers later.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new empty migration file in your terminal via `rails generate migration RenameUserFkOnQuestion`. Open it up and build your migration. [This is a handy guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) if you're not sure on the name of something.

```
def change
  change_table :questions do |t|
    t.rename :user_id, :author_id
  end
end
```

Run the migration and head over to your models. You'll need to update your relationships like so:

```
class Question
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end

class User
  has_many :questions, inverse_of: :author
end
```

Then you should be good to go.